# request querystring have np PayPal return variables

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I make a call to PayPal, after a successful transaction I do not get variables from PayPal regarding the transaction. 
Call follows-

**https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=myBussiness@gmail.com&item_name=myITEM&item_number=22&currency_code=USD&amount=5.00&shipping=5.00&tax_rate=10&rm=2&address_override=1&return=http://localhost:58377/thankyou.aspx&cancel_return=http://localhost:58377/notransaction.aspx&notify_url=http://localhost:58377/ppnotify.aspx**

Any idea why I do not get the variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal will not be able to find your notify url on your localhost.